# Issue about getting response in $.get()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
$('#requestButton').click(function() {
    $.get('ajax.php', function(data) {
        alert(data);
    });
});
```

`alert()` doesn't showing. What's the problem?

Comment: Who knows? You really haven't told us much. Have you checked the browser developer console at least?

Comment: I can think of about 10 things that can be wrong. Do some basic troubleshooting and provide details

Comment: Yes, AJAX request performed. alert() doesn't showing. It's about 15 minutes I trying to find out what's happining. ajax.php provide valid JSON

Comment: Look at your browser's developer tools. Look at the JavaScript console. Does it report any errors? Look at the Net tab. Is the request being made? Does it get a response? Do they contain the data you expect?

Comment: it could be possible you are getting error from `ajax.php`. try adding error callback function.

Comment: what is `$('#requestButton')` ... is this form related?

Comment: @Quentin that's the problem. request performed, everything seems to be ok, but that callback `function(data)` doesn't call.

Comment: @charlietfl Nothing, it's just a trigger for AJAX request.

Comment: Is the response right? Does it have the right content type? Does it have the right status code? Does it show the right content in the response body?

Comment: @Quentin `status: 200` `content-type: application/javascript` as I said, everything seems to be in order. But clever man answered my question and suggest to use `getJSON`. it's works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of :

```
$.get
```

use :

```
$.getJSON
```

As you mentioned in the comment section about returned data is `json`.

Or add a `dataType` in the `$.get()` call:

```
$.get( "ajax.php", function( data ) {
     console.log(data);
}, "json" ); //<-----------add dataType here
```

Comment: or fix header at server or add `dataType` argument to `$.get`

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that your server is claiming:

```
content-type: application/javascript
```

But you are sending back a JSON document. jQuery won't populate `data` when it gets (what it thinks is) a JavaScript program back from the server.

You need to send the correct content type, which is `application/json`.

Using `getJSON` or specifying `"json"` are hacks to tell jQuery to disbelieve the content type and parse in a different data format, but you should fix the server so it tells the truth about the content instead.

Comment: How many details! I edited ajax.php as you said and now it's working. Thank you.